# Execution plan - Hash Match

Tags: sql-server-2008, performance, execution-plan, query-performance

```
SELECT        dbo.Contracts.ContractID AS [Service Unit ID], dbo.Jobs.JobName, dbo.Customers.CustomerName, dbo.Contracts.ContractAutoID, dbo.Contracts.ContractType, dbo.Contracts.ContractStatus AS [Unit Status], 
                         dbo.Contracts.Area
FROM            dbo.Customers WITH (READPAST) INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Jobs WITH (READPAST) ON dbo.Customers.CustomerID = dbo.Jobs.CustomerID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Contracts WITH (READPAST) ON dbo.Jobs.JobID = dbo.Contracts.JobID
WHERE        (dbo.Contracts.ContractType = 'service')
```

I understand Hash Match indicates the indexing is not appropriate, which is why it takes up so much space. I am wondering what i need to different with my indexing to get these Hash Matches to become nested loops. Below is a picture of the Execution Plans.

> Customer Index
>
> Index Key Column: CustomerID
>
> Included Columns: City, CustomerStatus, CustomerName
>
> Contracts Index
>
> Index Key Column: ContractType
>
> Included Columns: ContractAutoID, JobID, Area, ContractStatus,
>   ContractID
>
> Jobs Index
>
> Index Key Column: JobID
>
> Included Columns: CustomerID, JobName, Area

[image]

Comment: After laboriously creating the DDL that you didn't supply http://pastebin.com/tdZKaCke I get a nested loops join with seeks so looks like it is just a cost based decision based on your data. No reason why the indexes you describe are inherently unsuitable for a nested loops plan with that query.

Comment: Query hints cant be used in this view. Sorry for not adding the DDL. i thought the query would be good enough. @MartinSmith

Comment: @ETA I don't think MartinSmith meant that you should use the hint but to prove that nested loop might be used. That plan is just not chosen by the optimizer (when there is no hint) for some reason (which is complicated, based on costs of the various plans examined by the optimizer)..

Comment: You might try an index on `(ContractType, JobID) INCLUDE (the rest)`

Comment: Wow. that made it a whole lot better. thank you @ypercubeᵀᴹ

Answer (score 1):

You could use `INNER LOOP JOIN` to cause a nested loop, but it may not improve the performance. Or  use an `OPTION (LOOP JOIN)` hint to still allow the optimiser to decide join order (which is forced by join hints).